# Google Cloud Endpoints: Return type of api method

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

In google cloud endpoints api class, I have following error while generating client endpoint library **for android client**:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type class java.lang.Boolean cannot be used as a return type

I have tried with other generic types as well, I guess api method can't return any generic object. I can't figure it out why this is not allowed in api method?

Is there any hack of this limitation?

```
/**
 * Returning error during client endpoint generation.
 */

@ApiMethod(name = "isValidEntity")
public Boolean isValidEntity(BusinessAccount businessAccount) {
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    Boolean isValid = false;
    try{
       .....
       ....
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

PS: I couldn't find enough documentation on api annotations other than [*Getting Started: cloud endpoint google documentation*](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/). I will appreciate if someone can point me to relevant sources.

Comment: same problems. 1)return single value like int, string, float etc is not allowed 2)return generic type is not allowed 3) return complex structure like map is not allowed 4)can't contain 2 or more complex type inside parameters. cry...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GPE docs say, "In the Endpoint methods, the return value type cannot be simple type such as String or int. The return value needs to be a POJO, an array or a Collection."

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-addentities

Comment: Thanks but any explanation why ?

Comment: At least String should have been supported.  It's not really a primitive type.